# Adding Body Padding to Body Does not Stop Navbar from Overlaying Body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried adding padding-top 70px; like instructed on the Bootstrap website but when I do so it does not fix my issue, when I click on a link to an ID in my page the top of it is still covered by my navbar. Can anybody take a look at this? I looked at other post with similar issue without success.

Here is the link to the website: https://canadashotokan45.herokuapp.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin

[download this plugin](https://github.com/garand/stickye)
and activation code is here

(1) put jquery.sticky.js in js folder and call it in HTML file

(2) put an ID on the navbar

(3) put js code on the bottom of HTML file

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:70});
  });
</script>
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="sticker">
  
  
</nav>
```